# Batch script to archive directory older than N days

Tags: batch-file

I have written a windows bat script to Archive the folders that are older than N days. Using this script I am able to Archive and move the files to the Archive folder but I am not able to delete the source folder from the source directory.
(After Archiving the folder and files inside the source is getting moved in the same tree structure to Archive but it is leaving empty folders in the source directory(files are getting deleted leaving empty folders behind))

Script

```
@echo off
setlocal
set SourceFolder=F:\work\script\Destination
set ArchiveFolder=H:\TEST\Archived
set Age=5
set FileMask=*.*
set LogFile=H:\TEST\result.log
>>"%LogFile%" echo ===== Archive job started: %Date% %Time% 
==========================
>>"%LogFile%" echo ===== Moving files older than %Age% days.
robocopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%ArchiveFolder%" /s /MOV /minage:%Age% /r:0 
/w:0 /tee /np /log+:"%LogFile%"
>>"%LogFile%" echo =====Archive job done" %Date% %Time% 
===============================
```

I need to modify this by deleting the folders in source after moving. Please suggest.

Comment: Use the `del` command to delete things.

Comment: Did you try /move instead?

Comment: `robocopy /?` from a command prompt will show you the options available. Make an effort to figure it out yourself using that information.

Comment: It's in help your error. You are telling to move files only.

Comment: but you are using `/MOV` which only moves and deletes files after copying, rather use `/MOVE` you can also look at `/PURGE` so try this instead. `robocopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%ArchiveFolder%" /s /MOVE /minage:%Age% /r:0`